# Teamcity Kotlin Scripts rename IDs

Tags: kotlin, teamcity

I have an auto generated Kotlin Script.

```
steps {
    script {
        name = "Style check"
        id = "RUNNER_633"
        enabled = false
        scriptContent = """
            #!/bin/bash
            
            make docker run="make ci lint"
        """.trimIndent()
    }
    script {
        name = "Build code"
        id = "RUNNER_662"
        scriptContent = """
            #!/bin/bash
            make docker run="make ci"
        """.trimIndent()
    }
    stepsOrder = arrayListOf("RUNNER_1213", "RUNNER_1228", "RUNNER_633", "RUNNER_662", "RUNNER_642")
}
```

- I really don't like the names RUNNER_633, RUNNER_1228 - which are values sometimes referenced in other kotlin script files.
- Can I rename them? What if I make mistake with the variable value? Is it possible to catch this before deploy and update of the teamcity?

Answer (score 1):

The **Versioned Settings** configuration has an option to also **use settings from VCS**. In this case you can push your changes of the settings to a branch and test them out by selecting your branch name in your build configuration.

[image: Versioned Settings]